# Turn on/off wifi with python on osx

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, phantomjs, wifi

It may be because of my ISP provider, sometimes when I am away, internet is down and it doesn't work until I restart wifi connection. So my script begins to raise timeout exception until I turn off and then turn on the wifi connection. Is there a efficent way to turn wifi on/off automatically with python 2.7 on osx el capitan?

Comment: Little google can help: http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/31/enable-disable-airport-wireless-connections-command-line/
Use subprocess module to execute

Comment: Well, I have googled it before I ask for sure and saw that page. But I didn't know the subprocess module and how to use it. docs will help I guess, thank you.

Comment: Please don't include solutions in the question. You should post an answer to your question yourself and then revert to an earlier revision of your question without the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> child = subprocess.Popen(["networksetup", "-setairportpower", "airport", "off"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output, error = child.communicate()
>>> print output
airport is not a Wi-Fi interface.
Turning off the only airport interface found: en1
```

Answer (score 9):

> SOLUTION:
>
> The easier and more efficent way to do this without using any complex or subprocess module:

```
import os 
os.system("networksetup -setairportpower airport off")
os.system("networksetup -setairportpower airport on")
```

> Thanks to **Hackaholic**